# comparing two groups on ordinal data with covariates

Tags: spss, nonparametric, ordinal-data, predictor

Hi I am using SPSS to compare two groups on ordingal data (frequency of substance use): never, 1-5/week, 6-10 week etc. The substance use data is highly skewed and non-transformable so ANOVA is out. I tried a Mann-Whitney U-test but SPSS gives error that ordinal data can not be entered. Moreover I need to covary for age, gender, and a few scale variables. Any ideas?

I thought of ordinal regression, but wasn't sure if I need to run this for each group separately and if so would I compare statistically the F-values. Thanks for any help with this.